# XDebug with IISExpress + PHP Tools for Visual Studio - ERROR

Tags: php, visual-studio

When trying to start the debug in Visual Studio I get this error:

[image]

Then when starting installation I get an error message:

[image]

I don't know what exactly to do to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try following the instructions in the error message? If you tried following the instructions what was the result?

Comment: There is not real any instructions given... its only a brief description, saying that PHP must be installed via the Web Platform. What does that mean?

Comment: Have a read here for some info [https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)